# Cannot compile webpack manifest

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, webpack, bundle

i cannot figure out why my `vendor.js` won't be recompiled. I upgraded my npm modules, changed my `vendor-manifest.json` and executed webpack, but my `vendor.js` doesn't changed. I have `webpack.config.js` and `webpack.config.vendor.js`.

I am using this Angular2 ASP.NET Core MVC 6 template and tried to upgrade to `Angular 2.1.0`, but without success.

Am I missing something? What do I have to do to recompile my `vendor.js`, based on my `vendor-manifest.json`?

Just let me know if you need the content of the specific files to help me debug this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing webpack for the webpack.config.vendor.js file:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

Comment: I used this to add npm with webpack to the ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application project. I was trying to get React set up in the MVC template, but M$ doesn't seem to have any documentation on how to do this.